# Git always ask for username and password in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, version-control

I recently shifted from windows to ubuntu.

I'm working on company's repo as collaborator and I do have all permissions. Git was working fine on my windows machine but in ubuntu it ask for username & password each time when ever i use git pull.

I tried to search different solution on google but nothing works for me.

**[Update]**

---

I was able to fix my issue by just signed in into github through visual studio code so i don't have to enter username and password multiple times.

Comment: Show the URL you're using (`git remote -v`). If it's https based, show the credential helper setup you've chosen; if it's ssh based, show any agent configuration you have set up, and whether you've used passphrase-protection for your ssh keys.

Comment: `origin https://github.com/companyName/projectName.git (fetch)`  
`origin https://github.com/companyName/projectName.git (push)`

Comment: To fix this issue, I signed in into github through visual studio code so i don't have to enter username and password multiple times

Comment: OK, it's https - that means Git will use a credential helper. If you're using VSCode, VSCode tweaks a lot of Git settings, so you should mention that in the original question. In any case, you can alter your credential helper; Ubuntu should be able to run the fancy new git-credential-manager one from MIcrosoft.

Answer (score 1):

I actually experienced this for so long. If Git prompts you for a username and password every time you try to interact with GitHub, you're probably using the HTTPS clone URL for your repository.

Here are the steps to solve this

1. install gh
   sudo apt-get install gh
2. gh auth login
3. Select if you want to auth to GitHub or GitHub enterprise. to select you to use the error down and enter
4. Select HTTPS
5. Select Yes
6. It will ask if you want to authenticate with the browser or paste tokens. I suggest auth with browser by selecting it
7. The one-time code will be displayed in your terminal and your default browser will be opened. then copy and paste them on the tap that is opened
8. Everything is good